# Are there any electric Turkish Coffee Makers without a mostly plastic or Teflon coated boiling pot?

Tags: turkish-coffee

Is there an electric Turkish Coffee Maker that doesn't have a mostly plastic or Teflon-coated boiling pot? I don't have a conclusive answer, but I cannot find such a product on the US market. This is a surprising development to me, but baring additional information from others, it seems to be the surprising truth.

For additional context, the following is an example of a plastic-only pot (other than the heating element). https://www.wayfair.com/kitchen-tabletop/pdp/saki-4-cup-automatic-turkish-coffee-pot-saki1050.html

Here is a direct answer from the manufacturer on Amazon about the plastic pot. Also, here is a product specification chart from Wayfair.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m afraid, but shopping advice has been a [difficult topic for over a decade on the SE network](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). In short, asking which X to get is inherently opinion-based and not helpful in the long term. I know we have been always a bit more lenient here, but this question is for me beyond that threshold.

Comment: @Stephie That's absurd. It's not opinion based at all. I was asking for something completely objective: to help find an electric Turkish coffee maker that has no plastic in its coffee pot.

Comment: Two things: First, we expect all users to follow the rules outlined in the Code of Conduct, including when talking to a moderator (and yes, we are pretty thick skinned overall). Second, mine is not the only close vote and I ran the case by the moderator team before closing. If you want to edit your question to ask e.g. what to look for in an electric Turkish Mokka maker, feel free to do so. If you disagree with the policy overall, take it to Coffee Meta, but note that [we already have a policy in place](https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/1118).

Comment: @Stephie The original question attracted a troll who thought it was fun to doubt the basic details I included. I didn't think I would get trolled by a moderator who called something inherently subjective which clearly isn't, but here we are.

Comment: @curiositasisasinbutstillcuriou I don't really follow, this is a product recommendation question, isn't it? If not, for example because you're asking about the approaches electric Turkish coffee maker manufacturers have used to avoid plastic in certain places then you should clarify by editing the question. In that case though, I think your answer doesn't fit that revised question because it merely recommends a product which is off-topic as Stephie pointed out in a previous comment.

Comment: @JJJ My answer now doesn't give a specific recommendation. I DON'T recommend the Arzum Okka electric Turkish Coffee. I came up empty. Look, I'm not here to get into exchanges with moderators. I'm hopeful that this question will now be acceptable with my current revisions. Thank you.

Comment: @curiositasisasinbutstillcuriou I think it's still phrased mostly as a product recommendation. To make it on-topic, I think you would have to phrase it to ask about the techniques that have been used to make non-plastic electric Turkish coffee makers. So rather than asking for specific products which is off-topic for the reasons outlined in the meta post Stephie linked, you would ask about techniques. Answers to the technical question are more useful because they're not location specific and they're still relevant even when a specific product is no longer on the market.

Comment: @JJJ Ok, thank you. I will modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a Arzum Okka electric Turkish Coffee model that had no plastic in the pot, but I was informed directly by the company (via e-mail) that their steel pot is coated in Teflon.

I don't believe that any product meets the criteria of the question.

Comment: I saw mention of an electric one, can't recall the brand.  But I couldn't figure out the heating element.  Makes me wonder if a microwave might work very well for Turkish coffee.  It would be very controlled....